# Find the $\lim_{n \to 0} (\cos(x)+\tan^2(x))^{\csc(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the $\lim_{x \to 0} (\cos(x)+\tan^2(x))^{\csc(x)}$

I've attempted logarithmic differentiation, in which I take 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} (\cos(x)+\tan^2(x))^{\csc(x)} = \exp\bigg(\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\ln(\cos(x)+\tan^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\bigg)$$

Using L'hopital rule, I've derived the following:

$$ = \exp\bigg(\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {-\sin(x) + 2\tan(x)\sec^2(x)}{\cos(x) + \tan^2(x)} . \frac {1}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}\bigg)$$

Now, I've derived that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {-\sin(x) + 2\tan(x)\sec^2(x)}{\cos(x) + \tan^2(x)} = 0$, which would then make the whole limit function $0 \implies e^0 = 1$, in which I doubt this question would be this easy.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: the searched Limit is indeed $1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} (\cos x+\tan^2 x)^{\csc x}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\left((1+(\cos x+\tan^2 x-1))^{\frac{1}{\cos x+\tan^2 x-1}}\right)^{(\cos x+\tan^2 x-1)\csc x}=$$

$$=e^{\ln\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\left((1+(\cos x+\tan^2 x-1))^{\frac{1}{\cos x+\tan^2 x-1}}\right)^{(\cos x+\tan^2 x-1)\csc x}\right)}=$$

$\ln$ is continuous, so you can switch $\ln$, $\lim$.

$$=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\ln\left(\left((1+(\cos x+\tan^2 x-1))^{\frac{1}{\cos x+\tan^2 x-1}}\right)^{(\cos x+\tan^2 x-1)\csc x}\right)}=$$

$$=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\left((\cos x+\tan^2 x-1)\csc x\right)\cdot \ln\lim_{x\to 0}\left((1+(\cos x+\tan^2 x-1))^{\frac{1}{\cos x+\tan^2 x-1}}\right)}=$$

$$=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\left((\cos x+\tan^2 x-1)\csc x\right)\cdot \ln e}=$$

$$=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\left((\cos x+\tan^2 x-1)\csc x\right)}=$$

$$=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}}\left(\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}\cdot x+\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}\right)=$$

$$=e^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{1}\cdot 0+0}=e^0=1$$

Answer (score 2):

simplifying the derivative of the numerator and denominator we get $$-{\frac { \left(  \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3}-2
 \right) \sin \left( x \right) }{ \left(  \left( \cos \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{3}- \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}+1
 \right)  \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$